# How to compare one array key value to another array index value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
$a=array([0]=>0 [1]=>3)

$b=array([0]=>image [1]=>profile [2]=>password [3]=>login)
```

i want to compare array a's key value i.e 0 to array b's index value 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
$a = array(0, 3);
$b = array(0 => 'image', 1 => 'profile', 2 => 'password', 3 => 'login');
$c = array_intersect_key($b, array_flip($a));
```

Results

```
Array
(
    [0] => image
    [3] => login
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **inarray** into foreach

```
<?php
$a = array(0,3);
$b= array('image','profile','password','login');


foreach($b as $key=>$value){
    if(in_array($key, $a)) {
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
image
login
```

Answer (score 0):

try  [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
array_intersect($a,$b);
```

or try `===` operator to compare the value in the array

```
<?php
  $a=array(0,3);
  $b=array(image,password);

 foreach($a as $k=>$v){

   if($a[$k]===$b[$k]){

     echo "$k  index is Same<br>";
   }else{

     echo "$k  index is different<br>";
   }


   }
```

**output**

```
0 index is different
1 index is different
```