# Match array key with array value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How to match array key with array value. 
With array_intersect() is to match key array.
But how to match key in first array with value in second array.

For example array:

```
$value_array=array(
'1'=>'text one',
'2'=>'text two',
'3'=>'text three',
'4'=>'text four',
'5'=>'text five',
'6'=>'text six',
'7'=>'text seven',
'8'=>'text eight',
'9'=>'text nine',
'10'=>'text ten'
);

$key_array=array(
'1'=>'1',
'2'=>'2',
'3'=>'4',
'4'=>'5',
'5'=>'7'
);
```

if use **array_intersect()**, is use to match key. I want to search key array and get value array. And output will show like this:

```
Array (
        [1] => text one 
        [2] => text two 
        [3] => text four 
        [4] => text five 
        [5] => text seven 
      )
```

Comment: Its duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696051/how-to-compare-one-array-key-value-to-another-array-index-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, here it is :

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($value_array, array_flip($value_key)));
```

and output will show:

```
    Array ( 
[1] => text one 
[2] => text two 
[4] => text four 
[5] => text five 
[7] => text seven 
)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is really a good way to do this. `array_flip` is adding extra load. Instead you can achieve using one single loop.